# UIImage returns nil but exists

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a problem in Swift.
I try to load an image which is stored in the DocumentsDirectory but it returns nil.

Here is the code:

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url!.path!) {
    //show image
    print("Image " + key + " exists")
    if let image =  UIImage(contentsOfFile: url!.path!){
        return image
    }
    else {
        print("error image")
        return nil
    }
}
```

I always got "error image" but the file exists. I don't understand the problem.

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: Do not use forced unwrap, you open the door to crashes if you use.

Comment: Ok, but it still does not load the image..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have rewritten your code into it's own function so you can test it with out having to change to your code too much. It works ok for me which leads me to suspect that your path is not set correctly or your code is failing to create an image from the file it accesses via the path you supply. The function below will tell you if the file does not exist **or** in UIImage failed to create the image.

You need to isolate where the error is occurring and start from there.

```
func getImage(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {

    var image : UIImage?

    if let path = url.path {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            if let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)  {
                image = newImage
            } else {
                print("getImage() [Warning: file exists at \(path) :: Unable to create image]")
            }

        } else {
            print("getImage() [Warning: file does not exist at \(path)]")
        }
    }

    return image
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I got: **/Users/henry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D475A874-0BCE-4BA7-9473-4FAAD866A52C/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC1C544D-EA34-4C5E-AE44-A6772FD1A44D/Documents/users/facebook_10153298923695141/PP_IMG_1450308308581.jpg :: Unable to create image]**

Comment: So you now know that something is up with the image. I would go and look at the image file and confirm that it a valid via a different app - i.e. open it in Preview :)

Comment: How can I check the image in Xcode? It is an image downloaded from Internet, that changes.. I cannot see the content of the Simulator in the Devices window.

Comment: Since you are using the simulator you can just go to the path  /Users/henry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D475A874-0BCE-4BA7-9473-4F‌​AAD866A52C/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC1C544D-EA34-4C5E-AE44-A6772FD1A44D/‌​Documents/users/facebook_10153298923695141/PP_IMG_1450308308581.jpg on your computer :) command + shift +g in finder window and paste path in!

Comment: Nice trick. Seems like the image was corrupted. I got it fixed. Thanks

Comment: Can you up vote the answer please, since you accepted it :)